# I hide (not to kill and hide) XBMC for raspberry pi?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, xbmc

I hide (not to kill and hide) XBMC for raspberry pi?

On xbmc I have written only a catalog, clicking on the item you want to run my app, while hide xbmc and start again as my app quits

I try to

```
xbmc.executeJSONRPC('{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"Input.ExecuteAction","params":{"action":"togglefullscreen"},"id":"1"}')
os.system('sleep 10') //run my app
xbmc.executeJSONRPC('{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"Input.ExecuteAction","params":{"action":"togglefullscreen"},"id":"1"}')
```

I took this code from a plugin that launches the application on MAC OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like that earned

```
xbmc.executeJSONRPC('{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"Input.ExecuteAction","params":{"action":"togglefullscreen"},"id":"1"}')
os.system('sh -c "sudo killall -STOP xbmc.bin && runmyapp && sudo killall -CONT xbmc.bin"') //run my app
xbmc.executeJSONRPC('{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"Input.ExecuteAction","params":{"action":"togglefullscreen"},"id":"1"}')
```